# The sum of unbounded sequence and bounded sequence in higher dimension

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have $\{a_n\}, \{b_n\} \in R^L$ such that $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded while $\{b_n\}$ is bounded. Prove that ${a_n + b_n}$ is unbounded.

I can solve it for $L = 1$ in a roundabout way but I'm having trouble with higher dimension. I want to prove that
$$\forall K \in R: ||a_n + b_n|| > K$$ for $n$ sufficiently large. The want to find a lower bound for $||a_n + b_n||$ but cannot come up with a good one because the only inequality I know related to the sum of two sequences is the Triangle Inequality, and that doesn't help here.

EDIT: I made this mistake of saying that $||a_n + b_n||$ diverges to infinity.

Comment: Prove it for arbitrary metric spaces, $(X\ d))\ $ -- then you'll see how easy is your problem, all it takes is the triangle inequality.

Comment: Maybe let $$S_k = \inf \left\{||a_k+b_n||: n\in \mathbf{N} \right\}$$ which always exists as $b_n$ is bounded. Then argue that $S_k \to \infty$ as $k\to \infty$

Comment: Let  $M=\sup_{j\in\Bbb N}\|b_j\|.$  Then $\|a_n+b_n\|\ge \|a_n\|-\|b_n\|\ge\|a_n\|-M.$

Comment: Most people think \|x\| produces a nicer look than ||x|| in LaTex.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$a_n = (a_n + b_n)-b_n$$

If $(a_n + b_n)$ was bounded, then $(a_n)$ would be the difference between two bounded sequences, and hence would be bounded. Contradiction.

Comment: you're right -- it should be ${a_n + b_n}$ is unbounded.

Comment: @Rainroad I edited.

Comment: ah yes of course. I've been trying to prove the wrong thing all along. Thanks!